# What are the advantages of objective c over c++?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the advantages of using Objective-C over C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112702/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-objective-c-over-c)

Can you please tell me what are the advantages of objective c over c++?
After reading objective c programming guide? i think c++ have the same if not similar features.

And why project like Webkit needs to use both c++ and objective c? My understanding is the Webkit common code is in c++ whereas the MacOS specified part is in objective c.

Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the advantages of using Objective-C over C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/112702/)